# How to emit an event from parent to child?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using Angular 2. Usually we use `@Output() addTab = new EventEmitter<any>();` and then `addTab.emit()` to emit an event to parent component.

Is there any way we can do it vice cersa, from parent to child?

Comment: Just change the value of an expression passed as Input to the child component, and the child component will get it (and be informed by ngOnChanges). You could also emit an event using a shared service that has an Observable.

Answer (score 428):

Using *RxJs*, you can declare a `Subject` in your parent component and pass it as `Observable` to child component, child component just need to subscribe to this `Observable`.

**Parent-Component**

```
eventsSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

emitEventToChild() {
  this.eventsSubject.next();
}
```

**Parent-HTML**

```
<child [events]="eventsSubject.asObservable()"> </child>
```

**Child-Component**

```
private eventsSubscription: Subscription;

@Input() events: Observable<void>;

ngOnInit(){
  this.eventsSubscription = this.events.subscribe(() => doSomething());
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.eventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Also, data can be passed along with the event using this approach. Like,`this.eventsSubject.next({data});` in the parent, then `this.events.subscribe(({data}) => doSomething(data));` in the child.

Comment: Probably a beginner question here: Why convert `eventsSubject` to an Observable instead of just subscribing to it as a Subject?

Comment: Converting eventsSubject to an Observable, prevent the child-component to call next().

Comment: in parent component eventsSubject should be public.

Comment: is this best practice?

Comment: What if the child component needs to subscribe to more than 1 event? What is the syntax for that?
`<child [events]="eventsSubject.asObservable()"> </child>`

Comment: @ErnestoE just name the `events` variable different than `events`. Maybe a more speaking variable name related to it's actual purpose. This way it is also easier for you to read what the event is for

Comment: Thanks for this solution, IT WORKS but I'm getting an error in the console:
   " core.js:6185   ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined "
The error is pointing to the events.subscribe() in the ngOnInit of the child component:

  " this.eventsSubscription = this.events.subscribe(() => doSomething()); "

I'm using the versions:  "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0" and "rxjs": "~6.5.4"

Comment: @Eduardo check your parent component html template, make sure "events" attribute bind correctly

Comment: It's generally agreed that in Angular [you should use `EventEmitter` not `Subject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular)

Comment: I am quite surprised that the answer got so many likes. Does it really a good practise to pass events into child component?
Which problems does it solve?
Why not to use just pass data and track it on changes or use some shared service?

Comment: I understand in part the @maskalek comment. I use something like this thinking it this way: "don't see it in terms of "Parent->Child" coms but in terms of a reusable component that delegates the responsibility in any host/user may have of knowing the exact event source."

Comment: You can use a "BehaviourSubject" instead of "Subject" to ensure the observer always give values, including initialization.

Comment: This solution works, but if you use ngOnChanges, it triggers it a lot of times whiout reason, so it looks like it's a bad pattern

Comment: y que es doSomething() , sale error , espera que esté declaro como una function . gracias.

Answer (score 137):

As far as I know, there are 2 standard ways you can do that.

**1. @Input**

Whenever the data in the parent changes, the child gets notified about this in
the ngOnChanges method. The child can act on it. This is the standard
way of interacting with a child.

```
// Parent-Component
public inputToChild: Object;
        
// Parent-HTML
<child [data]="inputToChild"> </child>       
        
//Child-Component
@Input() data;

ngOnChanges(changes: { [property: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    // Extract changes to the input property by its name
    let change: SimpleChange = changes['data']; 

    // Whenever the data in the parent changes, this method gets triggered
    // You can act on the changes here. You will have both the previous
    // value and the  current value here.
}
```

2. **Shared service concept**

Creating a service and using an observable in the shared service. The child
subscribes to it and whenever there is a change, the child will be notified. This is also a popular method. When you want to send something other than the data you pass as the input, this can be used.

```
// SharedService
subject: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();

// Parent-Component
constructor(sharedService: SharedService)
this.sharedService.subject.next(data);

// Child-Component
constructor(sharedService: SharedService) {
this.sharedService.subject.subscribe((data) => {
    // Whenever the parent emits using the next method,
    // you can receive the data in here and act on it.
});
```

Comment: I tried first method and it worked fine till some point and after that I got an error message stating The value got changed now, earlier it's false and now it's true. It did not give me any further explanation apart from this.

Comment: Given you mean a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, this error will not be thrown in production mode.

Comment: `<child [data]="inputToChild"> </child>` should probably be `<child [data]="(inputToChild)"> </child>` to get changes

Comment: When using the shared service, the service should be in the metadata header of the component class and not as a module. Module services are singletons, and thus global scope. Any variables stored there will linger and be global, likely causing defects and making bugs hard to discover. Good for configuration, bad for most other things.

Comment: What's the difference between using ngOnChanges and a setter on the input prop? Or are those two entirely different use cases?

Comment: there is a caveat with `onChanges` approach that if you fire the same value twice, it will be considered single because `onChanges` won't be fired as `@Input` has not changed yet.

Answer (score 72):

In a parent component you can use @ViewChild() to access child component's method/variable.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-number-parent',
  templateUrl: './number-parent.component.html'
})
export class NumberParentComponent {
    @ViewChild(NumberComponent)
    private numberComponent: NumberComponent;
    increase() {
       this.numberComponent.increaseByOne();
    }
    decrease() {
       this.numberComponent.decreaseByOne();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Angular 8 onwards -

```
@ViewChild(NumberComponent, { static: false })
```

Comment: This seems cleaner than working with observables. Drawback is child has to be in view. If the child is loaded with routing for example, this will fail as `numberComponent` will be `undefined`.

Comment: is this a good practice? i agree with the fact that's cleaner than observables, but i'm doubting about manipulate the child's variables from the parent. Anyway, it worked so nice for my needs, Thanks!

Comment: This is a good tip. Looks like @ViewChild is changed in Angular 8, or at least I had to specify options of the ViewChild. I used this in my case:
  @ViewChild(Other, { static: false })
  private otherComponent: Other;

Comment: { static: false } is default option in Angular 9+. Which means it's no longer necessary to be specified.

Comment: @BladeMaster Yes. You are right

Comment: This is a good solution when you have one child to "warn" of the event.
One can still use ViewChildren or accumulates those object in the parent of course.
The observable approach becomes interesting when you have heterogeneous children needing the event.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution, especially if you just need to check state of the child component, and not manipulate it. Amazing!

Answer (score 11):

Use the @Input() decorator in your child component to allow the parent to bind to this input.

In the child component you declare it as is :

`@Input() myInputName: myType`

To bind a property from parent to a child you must add in you template the binding brackets and the name of your input between them.

Example :

`<my-child-component [myChildInputName]="myParentVar"></my-child-component>`

But beware, objects are passed as a reference, so if the object is updated in the child the parent's var will be too updated.
This might lead to some unwanted behaviour sometime.
With primary types the value is copied.

To go further read this :

Docs : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous solutions worked for me because I had a Nested Recursive Child Component. So I used the following approach by using the OnChanges function.

**Parent Component**

```
buttonToggle: boolean = false;

buttonClick(): void {
  this.buttonToggle = !this.buttonToggle;
}
```

**Parent HTML**

```
<appNestedChildItemComponent [buttonTrigger]="buttonToggle"></appNestedChildItemComponent>
```

**Recursive Nested Child Component**

```
export class NestedChildItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() buttonTrigger: boolean;
  buttonToggle: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buttonToggle= buttonToggle;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['buttonTrigger'] && changes['buttonTrigger']?.previousValue != changes['buttonTrigger']?.currentValue) {
      this.buttonToggle= !this.buttonToggle;
      // Do Something triggered by the parent button.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That can only work if your child doesn't need to change buttonTrigger.

Answer (score 1):

Within the parent, you can reference the child using @ViewChild.  When needed (i.e. when the event would be fired), you can just execute a method in the child from the parent using the @ViewChild reference.

Comment: The child has to be in the view, otherwise it's not working (e.g. for multiple nested children).

Answer (score 0):

On the same concept of shared services: one can also use a local store with property management.
Parent(s) will update the state in the store and child(ren) may subsribe(s) to the store itself.

This approach makes it easier for many-to-many event/data/info transfers and can be applied the original question.

Drawback: heavier
Advantage: more robust to big app evolutions

One example of store management library I would recommend: https://github.com/ngneat/elf