# Trigger a change to children components in Angular 2, even though the data/state is not changes

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this parent components, that has a Boolean attribute, that can be set by user through a button in UI.

I have a recursive set of children components, a tree in fact, that need to response to change of that Boolean attribute, **even when the value of that Boolean attribute is not changed, but user has pressed that button**.

In other words, even if that Boolean attribute is `false`, and user clicks that button, and because of some logic the Boolean attribute is not changed at all and remains `false`, I still want the children components to be notified.

I'm using [`ngOnChanges`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053227/how-to-emit-an-event-in-angular-from-parent-to-child) and I'm [trying to trigger the event manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941635/how-to-trigger-a-change-event-manually-angular2).

But in case of `false` to `false`, which means no change, the `ngOnChanges` on children components is not called.

What do I miss here?

Comment: Why voting to close?

Comment: Why not use an `EventEmitter`?

Comment: @user184994, `EventEmitter` sends the event from children to parent. I want to send the event from parent to children.

Comment: Why not use a Subject or Observable then, and pass the subject as an Input to the child?

Comment: Can you guide me to a sample of that?

Comment: Sure. Which version of Angular / RXJS are you using?

Comment: Angular `6.0.6`, and RX.js `2.0`. Thank you.

Comment: ngDoCheck? https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#docheck

Answer (score 13):

You can pass a `Subject` as an input to the child components.

In your parent component, create a Subject, like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  subject = new Subject<string>();

  handleClick() {
    // This will send a message via the subject
    this.subject.next("TEST");
  }

  // Complete the subject when your component is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subject.complete();
  }
}
```

And pass it to the child component:

```
<hello [notifier]="subject"></hello>
```

In your child component, subscribe to the `Subject`, and do whatever you need to do in the subscribe callback:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() notifier: Subject<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.notifier != null) {
      this.notifier.subscribe((event) => {
        // This will be logged every time the subject.next is called.
        console.log("HelloComponent heard", event);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdjkge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)