# Angular: Unable to reset value in child component second time using @Input

Tags: angular, parent-child

Having a child component to handle dropdown. Parent component has a reset button to reset the selection made by the user to 'None' in the dropdown (child-component).

Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrjdck?file=src/app/app.module.ts) to the code.

***app.component.html***:

```
   <app-child [serverData]="serverData" [selectedInpValue]="selectedValue" (selectedComboBoxItemEvent)="getSelectedItem($event)"></app-child>
   <!-- reset button -->
   <button (click)="resetData()">Reset Selection</button>
```

2 @Input properties, **serverData** & **selectedInpValue** are sent to child component. *serverData* has the list for the dropdown and *selectedInpValue* holds the selected value. By default, **'None'** is displayed.

---

***server data***

```
this.serverData = [
      {
        'name': 'None',
        'value': 1,
        'isSelected': true
      },
      {
        'name': 'Debug',
        'value': 2,
        'isSelected': false
      },
      {
        'name': 'Error',
        'value': 3,
        'isSelected': false
      }
    ];
```

---

***child.component.ts***

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  selectedItem: any;

  @Input() serverData: any[];
  @Input() selectedInpValue: any;
  @Output() selectedComboBoxItemEvent = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedItem = this.serverData.find(data => data.isSelected);
    console.clear();
    console.log('child on init: ', this.serverData);
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.clear();
    console.log('child old selectedInpValue: ', this.selectedItem);
    this.selectedItem = this.selectedInpValue;
    console.log('child new selectedInpValue: ', this.selectedItem);
  }

  selectItem() {
    const index = this.serverData.findIndex(x => x.value === this.selectedItem.value);
    this.serverData[index].isSelected = true;
    for (const data of this.serverData) {
      if (data.value === this.selectedItem.value) {
        data.isSelected = true;
      } else {
        data.isSelected = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

***child.component.html***

```
<select (change)="selectItem()" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option *ngFor="let listItem of serverData" [ngValue]="listItem">{{ listItem.name }}</option>
</select>
```

---

Issue:

- user selects 'Debug' and clicks on **Reset Selection**, the selctions resets to *None*.
- user again selects Debug/Error and clicks on **Reset Selection**, nothing happens.

First & second click of **Reset Selection** makes **selectedInpValue** as-

```
selectedInpValue = {
        'name': 'None',
        'value': 1,
        'isSelected': true
      }
```

Since, on the second click, the input property *selectedInpValue* holds the same value as on the first click, the *ngOnChanges* does not trigger and reset does not happen.

How do I solve this?

Comment: use this `@Input() set serverData(value) {}`

Comment: I am still unable to achieve it. See if you can make changes in the code for my better understanding. Link is provided in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to asign the value of selectedItem, the first who has a propertie of isSelected equal true, you should use a getter in input, not the ngOnInit

```
  selectedItem: any;
  _serverData:any[]
  @Input()
  set serverData(value)
  {
    this._serverData=value;
    this.selectedItem = this.serverData.find(data => data.isSelected);
  }
  get serverData()
  {
     return this._serverData
  }
```

Second to "change" an array you need create a copy, not change individual element. You think an array as a point of the memory, you change the content, but the position of memory is the same.

```
resetData() {
    this.serverData[0].isSelected = true;
    this.serverData=[...this.serverData]
  }
```

[your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ar2xqg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You need top add a simple change detection event at children component like below mentioned

```
ngOnChanges(changes: { [property: string]: SimpleChange }) {  

// Extract changes to the input property by its name    

let change: SimpleChange = changes['data'];  

// Whenever the data in the parent
changes, this method gets triggered. You    can act on the changes
here. You will have both the previous value and the    current value
here.  
}
```

for more detail you can check this answer.

[How to emit an event from parent to child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053227/how-to-emit-an-event-from-parent-to-child)

Answer (score 0):

You can use set function. this function is call on every change of input. if you can update serverdata value some value reflect on child component

```
@Input() set serverData(value) {
  // do some task
}
```

Comment: I am still unable to achieve it. See if you can make changes in the code for my better understanding. Link is provided in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change every time reference of it, like

```
this.selectedValue = Object.assign({}, this.selectedValue);
```

please check the working code here [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2z85lx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The parent is not being informed when the child updates the data.The 1st time the parent sends the None option. Then the child updates the data. And after that, the parent sends again the None option which correctly remains the same as the previous input, so the ngOnChanges does not fire. So you can pass a third input (e.g. a boolean) which values is being updated on each Click on reset

Parent

```
updateChild:boolean = false;

resetData() {
    this.serverData[0].isSelected = true;
    this.selectedValue = this.serverData[0];
    this.updateChild = !this.updateChild;
}

<app-child [serverData]="serverData" [selectedInpValue]="selectedValue" [reset]="updateChild"
  (selectedComboBoxItemEvent)="getSelectedItem($event)" ></app-child>

<button (click)="resetData()">Reset Selection</button>
```

Child

```
 @Input() reset:any;
```

Comment: rather then expose new property what about this this.selectedValue = Object.assign({}, this.selectedValue); I think it will do the same

Comment: this.selectedValue = Object.assign({}, this.selectedValue); is also a good and clean approach